# Pandas: Create new column with substring from other column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, substring

I have various columns which contains values like this:

```
FSA: 123.45 US DOLLAR 
FSA: 67.89 JAPANESE YEN
```

I would like to create a new column that contains this:

```
123.45
67.89
```

The 'FSA: ' is a constant value, but the currency type and amount will vary.
What is an efficient method for achieving this without having to go row by row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `str.extract`:

```
>>> df['Col'].str.extract(r'(\d+\.?\d*)').astype(float)
      Col
0  123.45
1   67.89
```

Input:

```
>>> df
                       Col
0    FSA: 123.45 US DOLLAR 
1  FSA: 67.89 JAPANESE YEN
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! I didn't even think to use str.extract() I had my mind set on using str.contain()